# How to add Custom class or ID on Magenot 2 Product Admin Grid Columns

Tags: magento2, product, grid, custom, class

How to add the custom class or ID on Magento 2 Product Admin Grid Columns basically I want to add a class or id on ( qty, price, name, SKU ) on these fields.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Need to create a custom module and add this.

File Path : app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml

Argument part also disabled the link on rows i need that so posted here if anyone needed that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd"> 
<columns name="product_columns">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">product_listing.product_listing.product_columns_editor</item>
                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                    <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                        <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <column name="entity_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="fieldClass" xsi:type="string">tnbl_product_id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="name">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="fieldClass" xsi:type="string">tnbl_product_name</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="sku">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="fieldClass" xsi:type="string">tnbl_product_sku</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="qty">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="fieldClass" xsi:type="string">tnbl_product_qty</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="price">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="fieldClass" xsi:type="string">tnbl_product_price</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
</columns>
```